# Destacar uma linha da tabela quando dou click no polígono do mapa

Tags: javascript, array, react, typescript, next.js

```
const [Id] = React.useState<number | null>(null);
    
  function handleRowClick(row: Row<Fazenda>) {
    setSelectedRowId(row.id); 
    rowClickCallback(row.original);
  }


 {table.getRowModel().rows.map(row => (
            <tr 
              key={row.id}
              className={selectedRowId === row.id ? 'selected' : ''} 
              onClick={() => handleRowClick(row)}
              >
              {row.getVisibleCells().map(cell => (
                <td key={cell.id}>
                  {flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
```